# Range selection using date-picker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

used a jquery library to create a datepicker and tried to make a range selection .

Here is what i did so far:

```
    $(function () {
    // Si minimum_retail (minimum à prendre en jour) est supp à 1
    if (minimum_retail > 1) {
        weekpicker = 'week'
    } else {
        weekpicker = false;
    }

    $('#datepicker').dateRangePicker({
        firstDay: 2,
        alwaysOpen: true,
        format: 'DD/MM/Y',
        separator: ' au ',
        minDays: minimum_retail,
        startOfWeek: 'monday',
        batchMode: weekpicker,
        maxDate: "+1y",
        language: 'fr',
        inline:true,
        container: '#datePicker',
        showTopbar: false,
        beforeShowDay: function(date){
            var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
            return [ unavailableDates.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: Can u make ur code runnable here so I can assist you?

Comment: I left from a github bookstore there is no CDN https://longbill.github.io/jquery-date-range-picker/

Comment: Look at here also: http://www.daterangepicker.com

Comment: I saw this one too but I do not feel like we can do a week selection